# How to revert setTint() to default colors?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to add two functions to the `View` class: `enable()` and `disable()`. The idea is to be able to change the look of a Button in order to be gray when disabled and colorful when enabled. To make the button gray, I use `background.setTint(Color.GRAY)` which works well. The problem is that I can't find a way to revert the original tint color of the button.

I've already tried using `background.clearColorFilter()` to clear the gray filter, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the best solution would be to create a color selector, something like

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:color="@color/X" />
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/Y" />
</selector>
```

(defined inside the `res/color` folder) and then associate it to your button's background.
In the example above, `@color/X` should correspond the background color once the button is enabled, `@color/Y` when disabled.